# connect nodejs to mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have following code that connect nodejs to mysql. When I run it the first time it work the data print out to the page but when I refresh the page it tell 'This site can’t be reached' 'localhost refused to connect.' I don't understand why I can connect to server only the first time. I use url as localhost:3000/car

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'joeM',
  password : 'versus',
  database : 'joe'
});

app.get('/car', function(req, res){

  connection.connect();

  connection.query('SELECT * FROM test1', function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;

    var print = '<ol>';
      for( var i = 0; i<rows.length; i++){
      print +=('<li>ID:' + rows[i].id + ' Brand:' + rows[i].brand +'</li>' );
      }
      print += '</ol>';
      res.send(print);
      connection.end();
    });
  });

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('Magic Happen at port: 3000');
});
```

Comment: @farhadamjady Thank you very much

Comment: your welcome! @Joe

Answer (score 0):

dont use connection.connect(); in every request and set it out of request block